# npm package.json and docker (mounting it...)

Tags: node.js, npm, docker

I am using Docker, so this case might look weird. But I want my whole `/data` directory to be mounted inside my docker container when developing.

My `/data` folder container my `package.json` file, an `app` directory and a bunch of other stuff.
The problem is that I want my `node_modules` folder to NOT be persistent, only the `package.json` file.

I have tried a couple of things, but `package.json` and `npm` is giving me a hard time here...

- Mounting the `package.json` file directly will break npm. npm tries to rename the file on save, which is not possible when its a mounted file.
- Mounting the parent folder (`/data`) will mount the node_modules folder.
- I cant find any configuration option to put node_modules in another folder outside `/data`, example `/dist`
- Putting `package.json` in `/data/conf` mounting the `/data/conf` as a volume instead wont work. I cant find any way to specify the `package.json` path in `npmrc`.
- Putting `package.json` in `/data/conf` and symlinking it to `/data/package.json` wont work. npm breaks the symlink and replaces it with a file.

Copying data back and forth to/from inside the docker container is how I am doing it now.. A little tedious.. I also want a clean solution..

Comment: It's a heavy handed instrument, but would a unionfs overlay not solve your problems?

Comment: Since the file is visible as a mountpoint inside the container, it woulnt matter. It's not able to rename (replace) the file, since it will be disconnected from the mountpoint after the replacement..

Comment: I did this by using the global install path: http://www.saulshanabrook.com/npm-docker-sharing-volumes/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you have already answered, I think that might be the only solution right now.

When you are building your Docker image, do something like:

```
COPY data/package.json /data/
RUN mkdir /dist/node_modules && ln -s /dist/node_modules /data/node_modules && cd /data && npm install
```

And for other stuff (like bower, do the same thing)

```
COPY data/.bowerrc /data/
COPY data/bower.json /data/
RUN mkdir /dist/vendor && ln -s /dist/vendor /data/vendor && cd /data && bower install --allow-root
```

And `COPY data/ /data` at the end (so you are able to use Dockers caching and not having to do npm/docker installation when there is a change to `data`.

You will also need to create the symlinks you need and store them in your git-repo. They will be invalid on the outside, but will happely work on the inside of your container.

Using this solution, you are able to mount your `$PWD/data:/data` without getting the npm/bower "junk" outside your container. And you will still be able to build your image as a standalone deployment of your service..

Answer (score 6):

I've been having this problem for some time now, and the accepted solution didn't work for me*

I found a blog post (link is dead now), which had an edit pointing to [a Compose file](https://github.com/pypa/warehouse/blob/7860ffcdba3fb93e5e42254aa53486a0f75f1d9a/docker-compose.yml#L22-L24) and this indeed worked for me:

```yaml
volumes:
  - ./:/data
  - /data/node_modules
```

In this case the Engine creates a [volume](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) which is not mounted to your source directory. This was the easiest solution and didn't require me to do any symlinking, setting paths, etc.

For reference, my simple Dockerfile just looks like this:

```
# install node requirements
WORKDIR /data
COPY ./package.json ./package.json
RUN npm install -qq

# add source code
COPY ./ ./

# run watch script
CMD npm run watch
```

(The `watch` script is just `webpack --watch -d`)

Hope this is able to help someone and save hours of time like it did for me!

---

'*' = I couldn't get `webpack` to work from my `package.json` scripts and installing anything while inside the container created the `node_modules` folder with whatever I just installed (I run `npm i --save [packages]` from inside the container to update the `package.json` until the next rebuild)

Answer (score 5):

A similar and alternative way is to use NODE_ENV variable instead of creating a symlink.

`RUN mkdir -p /dist/node_modules
RUN cp -r node_modules/* /dist/node_modules/
ENV NODE_PATH /dist/node_modules`

Here you first create a new directory for node_modules, copy all modules there, and have Node read the modules from there.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I went with was placing the node_modules folder in `/dist/node_modules`, and making a symlink to it from `/data/node_modules`. I can do this both in my Dockerfile so it will use it when building, and I can submit my symlinks to my git-repo. Everything worked out nicely..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can save your container, and then rebuild it regularly with a minimal Dockerfile:

```
FROM my_container
```

and a `.dockerignore` file containing:

```
/data/node_modules
```

See the doc:
http://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#the-dockerignore-file

Comment: In a development face when there is a lot of changes and using fig to spin up the env this is not a good solution. The only problem is this package.json file, none of the others. This solution will also complicate everything a lot..